# Detecting changes in share permissions

Tags: network-share

I was wondering if there's a way to detect changes in share permissions apart from enabling auditing, something that would show you what was there before and what has been changed.

This would be useful if by mistake you edit the permissions at the root share and instead of adding you accidentally click on Yes at the pop-up to replace them.

How would you know what permissions you replaced, for restore purposes, if the share is rather big?

Answer (score 1):

You can install and use `auditd` for information on who changed the permissions but there isn't any way to tell what they were in the past.

The only way to achieve your objective would be to create a script to read and output the permissions at timed intervals so that you can compare them to what they currently are.